# Extracting integers from string and saving them into linked lists

Tags: c, string, struct, linked-list, integer

I wrote a code that saves contents from a file to a linked list.
However I want to extract the ages and save them into a int array.
For example Martha will be stored into name and 12 will be stored into age.

I have been thinking about ways to implement it but I can't come up with a proper solution.

The code below stores martha 12 into a char array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#define MAXN 50    
#define val 2
typedef struct node {
    char name[MAXN];
    //int value[val];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *file = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (file == NULL)
        return 1;

    char buf[MAXN];
   // int buf2[val];

    node *first = NULL, *last = NULL;   


    while (fgets (buf, MAXN, file)) {

        node *head = malloc (sizeof(node));
        if (head == NULL) {         
            perror ("malloc-node"); 
            return 1;   
        }


        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;    


        strcpy (head->name, buf);
        head->next = NULL;


        if (!last)
            first = last = head;
        else {
            last->next = head;
            last = head;
        }


    }

    if (file != stdin)  
        fclose(file);

    node *ptr = first;              
    while (ptr != NULL) {           
        node *node_t = ptr;         
        printf ("%s\n", ptr->name); 
        ptr = ptr->next;            
        free (node_t);              
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the input file:

```
Martha 12
Bill 33
Max 78
Jonathan 12
Luke 10
Billy 16
Robert 21
Susan 25
Nathan 20
Sarah 22
```

Any Suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please narrow down the problem. Can store and retrieve values to/from your linked list if the values are hardcoded? Can read and print values from the file without storing to linked list? Please edit the question to only demonstrate the remaining problem.

Comment: The remaining problem is to extract the integer from the string and storing it into a int array for each node

Comment: So when you say "saver into linked list" and "store in an int array" you mean completely different things? (I was thinking that you just used "array" instead of linked list.)

Comment: You want to store a string like "Martha", accompanied by an int like 12 into an int array? Please explain more about that.

Comment: Why don't you save it directly to array from file?

Comment: @Yunnosch I want to seperate martha 12. For example in the first node I will have char name and int age.  So  martha will be saved in name  and 12 will be saved in age. That is what I was thinking about

Comment: What is `age`? Is it supposed to be in the `struct node`? Very unclear question and very weird approach.

Comment: BTW this looks somewhat like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are yolu _actually_ trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah it's supposed to be in the struct node. Then seperate the name and the age of martha and the others into the arrays in the node

Comment: @momonosuke read my very last comment, and click on the link "XY problem" therein. And then tell us what you actually want to do with the data in the list and/or int the array or whatever. Maybe your overall approach is all wrong, but it's hard to tell without more background information.

Comment: @momonosuke If you want split data in `value` and `name`,  just use `sscanf()` then put those value in linked list.

Comment: @Jabberwocky . I want to read the the contents of an input file and store them into a linked list. The input file contains name and age. For each node there is a char array for the name and an int array for the age. However the code that I have provided below stores everything into a char array. I dont know how change my code so that it stores name and age seperately.

Comment: @SayedSohan so fgets is the wrong approach?

Comment: @momonosuke no.. See my answer below how I split data with `sscanf()` using `fgets()` .

Comment: @momonosuke in that answer I used array to store all data but you can just take 2 variable and store them linked list in same loop. as you did in your solution

Comment: @SayedSohan so in my loop I should use sscanf to store the name into char array and the age into int array?

Comment: @momonosuke you no need to use array. I am Editing my answer with your code. wait 2 mins.

Comment: Look closely at your list creation. It's all wrong and it doesn't work at all. Focus on that first and only on that. Once the code that creates the list is correct, you can move on.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry for confusing you and the others. That means my code dosen't create any list? I thought that my code creates a linked list. For example node 1 has the string martha 12 node 2 has the string Bill 33 and they are all linked together

Comment: @SayedSohan ok thanks

Comment: The list is constructed ok, although naming is somewhat backwards. Matter of taste I suppose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need an array for the `value`, only `int`. Also I would use uppercase `N` for the `typedef` and change the variable declarations accordingly (`Node *head;`)

```
typedef struct node {
    char name[MAXN];
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} Node;
```

Instead of copying the line you just read with `strcpy`, you should parse the string with `sscanf` and assign the values to the `struct`. Notice that we put `&` operator before referring to `head->value`, because we need the pointer to the `value`:

```
sscanf(buf, "%s %d", head->name, &head->value);
```

For error handling you could also check the number of returned values:

```
if(sscanf(buf, "%s %d", head->name, &head->value) != 2) {
    /* Do some error handling */
}
```